# What does 丫 mean? 丫是什么意思？

Tags: usage, word

I'm currently watching a TV show called ”匆匆那年“, at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0Tub19BTX4&list=PLn8V6LgDVrvJ3SAHEtI4i6hEL_ODIulko&index=7. I've only watched half an hour of the seventh episode, but I've already heard the word "丫" a few times. For example, at 30:22, one of the characters says, "你丫不会要哭吧“, and I understand what the sentence means, but **why is “丫" used and what does it mean? I've never heard it in China, is it used in some parts of China and others not? Are there only certain contexts when it could be used?** Unfortunately, I can't find the other times I heard it in that episode currently, but I know I heard it and saw it a few times. I've tried searching on Google and various online translators, but I couldn't find a conclusive answer on when to use it or what it means.

我正在看一个电视节目叫”匆匆那年“。我就看了半个小时的第七集，已经听过了一些次句话用“丫”。比如，在这个 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0Tub19BTX4&list=PLn8V6LgDVrvJ3SAHEtI4i6hEL_ODIulko&index=7) 的30:22，一个人说，”你丫不会要哭吧“。我听懂这句话的意思，**可是“丫”是什么意思，而且为什么需要用它? 我在中国没听过了，有的中国部分用它很多，有的没用它吗？** 不好意思，我现在不会找到那些其他次我听过了“丫”，但是我知道我听过了它。我在Google上查资料了它，也不会找到一个好的解答。谢谢！

另外，我知道我的中文不好，如果你会改善我的写作，请帮我！

Comment: 那可能是臺灣的注音符號「ㄚ」，代表「啊」或「呀」。

Comment: 另外，我知道我的中文不好，如果你会改善我的写作，请做！ better change to 另外，我知道我的中文不好，如果你能改善我的写作，请帮我！[reason你会帮我吗?你能帮我吗is different，请做sounds weird ]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a short word for "丫头养的" only used in area around Beijing city，"丫头" means slave girl or young girl servant. "养的" means feed by.

This is bad language saying somebody's mother is young girl servant, some kind of "son of bitch". However this talking is generalized nowadays, "你丫..." is more compare to "You fucking ..."(你他妈的...)

Answer (score 8):

"你丫" is a phrase from Beijing dialect. The word "丫" itself doesn't have a meaning in this context. It is a slang, not an appropriate way of speaking. You can think of it as adding F words in an English sentence. "你丫" is not as flexible as the F word though. For example, you can't say "他丫". This is a special phrase only appear in the second person pronoun context.

I can't find a better source for this phrase than this one on Baidu's wiki site: https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%BD%A0%E4%B8%AB%E7%9A%84

Answer (score 4):

Rule of thumb, think of 丫 as "motherfucker".

Actual meaning of the word depends on the context and tone.

Most of the time, it is just a word use between close friends.

> 你不会要哭吧?
> Wait, are you gonna cry?
>
> 你丫不会要哭吧?
> Wait, you motherfucker gonna cry?

It can be used for emphasis, or mean a plain insult, show hostility.

> 你能不能客气点啊?
> Can't you be nice? (Mild complaint)
>
> 你丫能不能客气点啊?
>
> Can't you motherfucker be nice?  (A bit stronger)
>
> You motherfucker can't say it nicely, can you? (Guy stands up, gonna start a fight)

Like "motherfucker", you don't use it easily to strangers, that'll gets you into trouble. Mostly it's used between friends.

Answer (score 4):

“你丫” is an abbreviated version of "你这个丫头养的" or “你是丫头养的” = 你是丫环生的

你丫 = You (more precisely = You the bastard)
So "丫"(or the full version of 丫头养的）is a qualifier for "你you".

丫头 or丫环, 丫鬟 = maid （often young and poor, coming from a peasant family）.  养的 = 生的.

i.e. You are a bastard, your mother is not a respected lady, but a maid who had sex with her master, that's why you exist.

Sometimes people simply use this one word “丫” , in this case, it often means "He" or that guy, that bastard.

Answer (score 3):

https://bkrs.info/slovo.php?ch=%E4%B8%AB 3)girl 
4) dial. 
丫的 Beijing dialect, vulg. he,she,you (orig. 丫头养的, 丫挺的, i.e. illegitimate (born out of wedlock) child)
(of course 丫头 is well known)
more examples: ０：５０：我让你丫滚蛋 １：１１：合着你们丫都知道吗 １：１７：你丫脑袋也开窍了８：２０：你丫能不能客气啊８：２４：你丫自己心里有火 １０：１２：丫有病 １３：０６：丫就是一变态 (丫 by itself)

additional slang,colloquialisms, technical sports terms (using bkrs): awesome 牛:
６：４２；全国最牛的高中篮球比赛１８：０４：挺牛了20:59:太牛了那球啊 
８：１２：你能别这么磨叽（(dialect) to dawdle
to waste time）吗
８：３２：屁大（coll. unimportant; minor）点事至于吗这么磨叽了，至于吗（seriously?, why?, really?), ８：４０：说你了这么着（这样、如此）瞧你那德行
１２：０４：我让你挡拆挡拆（pick and roll (basketball)
screen and roll）２１：０８：如果不是最后回振的那个绝杀（to deal the fatal blow (sports, chess etc)）
to score the winning point

Comment: But in the sentence "你丫不会要哭吧", there's already a "you". Is that common?

Comment: I think 丫 is not 'you' but  an 'adjectival noun' of pronoun including 'you'

Comment: How about 我丫 then?

Comment: 丫 by itself seems to confirm as another answer said,that it is an interjection/expletive (like "damn (it)"), bkrs apparently needs updating

Answer (score 2):

你丫的 is a milder interjection compared with 你妈的. You could say:

> 妈的，你不会要哭吧？
>
> 丫的，你不会要哭吧？

你丫的 is less vulgar than 你妈的.

Answer (score -1):

丫 means "why", like Y, and is used when you happen to have a question about a subject.